# How to resize UITextField height as user types in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I want to change the textField height as the user types in it.
How can I do it?

I don't want to use a `TextView`.

Answer (score 4):

Every `UITextField` comes with an action **Editing changed**, you can drag and drop as an action to your class.

In this method, you can probably change the constraint that defines the height of the `UITextField`. Make sure to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` to update the constraint you just changed. For example:

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    editTextHeight.constant += 2.0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Hi @ Aline Kolczycki Borges, I get this error message: user of unresolve identifier 'editTextHeight'. Thank you

Comment: Hi @KerbyJean this is a `@IBOutlet` of the height constraint of the UITextField. I know it is too late to tell you that :)